# How to style mat-option text to get the text outside mat-select panel on hovering over every mat-option text

Tags: css, angular, typescript, mat-autocomplete

I want to style hovering on each mat-option text,  I wan the text to displayed outside mat-option. In order to achieve this, I applied z-index of very high value, but nothing changed.
I tried add z-index to higher value but this hasn't worked out.

I was inspired by the following [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/romvkygmaaa)

This is the current behaviour

[image]

Here is what I need
[image]

Here is the code snippet

**template.html**

```
<mat-form-field [style.cursor]="pointer"  [style.width.px]=450 >
  <input  id="inputCustomer" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto"  [formControl]="customerFilterControl" [(ngModel)]="customerName">

   <mat-autocomplete  style="left:775px;" #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith] = "displayFn" >
    <mat-option  (onSelectionChange)="onCustomerChange(customer)" [value] ="customer.AccountID +' '+'('+ customer.AccountName + ')'">
       <span>{{customerName}}</span>
  <span id="para2">{{customerName}}</span>
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

**template.ts**

```
  customer:Array<any>;
  filteredOptions: Observable<any[]>;
  customerFilterControl = new FormControl();
customer =[
{
AccountID :1,
AccountName:"account1"
},
{
 AccountID:2,
 AccountName:"account2"
},
{
 AccountID:3,
 AccountName:"Earliest_Creation_Date_Ent_Tests_id7 (Earliest_Creation_Date_Ent_Tests_id7accountName)"
}

  displayFn(subject) {
    return subject ? subject : undefined;  
  }


onCustomerChange(customer) {
this.filteredOptions = this.customerFilterControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  map(value => this._filter(value))
 );  
}


  _filter(value:any):any[] {

    const filterValue = value;
    return this.customers.filter(function (option) {
       if(option.AccountID.includes(filterValue) | option.AccountName.includes(filterValue)) {
          return option;
        }
    }); 
  }
```

**template.scss**

```
#para2 {
display:none;
}
.mat-option:hover {
  background-color: white !important;
  z-index:500000 !important;
  width:440px !important;
  word-break: break-all !important; 
}


.mat-option-text {
  padding-left: 60px !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
  text-overflow: unset !important; 
}


.mat-option {

    &:hover {
        white-space: unset!important;
        overflow: unset !important;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;


        #para2
        {

            z-index:500000 !important;
            width:400px !important;
            word-break: break-all !important; 
            display: block;
            position: relative !important;
            overflow: visible !important;
            text-align: left;
            top:0px;
            right:50px !important;
            background-color: #232F34;
            color:#FFFFFF;
            border: 5px !important;
            font-size:11px;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is missing parts making is difficult to reproduce the issue. E.g. `customerFilterControl` is missing.

Comment: Sorry I will update the question

Comment: I have updated the question , customerFilterControl :FormControl. Let me know if more info is needed

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's going on here, the code seems to be riddled with mistakes. I've created a Stackblitz for you [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e2vbzj-jvl6bw) if you'd like to explain further.

Comment: Hi viqas, I have two span elements, one of them is made display:none but when hovering over mat-option, both the span appears, <span id="para2">{{c.AccountName}}</span>. I have edited the stackbilitz https://angular-e2vbzj-jvl6bw.stackblitz.io/

Comment: I have added the new span tag and made para2 display: none by default in the question

Comment: Hi, any suggestion or will this be possibel or not?

Comment: I'm really not sure as I don't understand what/why you want to do.

Comment: Its mat-autocomplete when I hover over each mat-option, I want to get style as shown in the figure above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205873/discussion-between-karansys-and-viqas).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using matTooltip for each mat-option when hovering above each option?

Add a

```
matTooltip="{{state.name}} | Population: {{state.population}}"
```

on mat-option and the angular material does the rest.

check working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ksabb1)